# Does ticker.C leak memory, if run forever?

Tags: loops, go, memory-leaks

I've searched stack overflow for something similar to this, and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. I apologize if this is an obvious mistake as I just recently started writing in Go, but I appreciate any explanation in advance.
I currently have a go routine that ranges over the values of `*Ticker`.
Now this go routine runs the entire time my program is alive, as it checks for necessary updates. I started recognizing that my program leaks memory slowly overtime. It starts to become very noticeable after 20 to 30 hours of running.

```
func (s *Server) checkForUpdates() { // go routine
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Minute * time.Duration(s.checkTime)) //x.checkTime = 2 minutes
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for t := range ticker.C { // will loop every 2 minutes
         fmt.Println("the update check happened at %d\n", t)
         // do the updates
    }
}
```

I narrowed the leak down to the go routine, and read up on all the way's Time can leak memory. Making sure that you close the `*Ticker` you created once your done with the go routine. However my program runs forever until I kill it. So this go routine will forever run, until I decide to stop the program. 
I know this might be silly to think, but I thought it might be the `t := range ticker.C` part that could be the problem. Because that loop never stops until I kill. So `t` never get's released. So I thought the `:=` re-declares the variable every time I loop? I then made the loop to :

```
for _ = range ticker.C { // completely got rid of declaration of time.Time
   // do updates ...
}
```

And so far it seems to be working... but I really don't understand why, or maybe it should have not helped, and there's something else I'm doing wrong.

I appreciate any help/explanation for this. Thank you.

Comment: The application is using the ticker correctly.  If the leak is in this goroutine, then the problem is in `// do updates`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The value you get back in the loop is just the time the ticker went off, it's likely allocated on the stack, and only lives for the duration of one loop iteration. It cannot leak. The ticker, if it is meant to have the lifetime of your application, also by definition cannot leak. Can you perhaps elaborate on what makes you think you have a memory leak and how you identified the quoted code as the source of the leak?

Comment: If the ticker causes a memory leak, that means there's a very serious bug in Go, because the ticker is essentially just a channel.

Comment: Go shipts with a next level tool called `pprof` which will help you trace the exact source of memory leak in your program by showing the total memory used and/or the total allocated per statement.  There are tons of blog posts online about how to use this (and great documentation on golang.org).  
I tried my hand at explaining it too https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/sre-debugging-simple-memory-leaks-in-go-e0a9e6d63d4d

Comment: Thank you all for your help, and clarifications. 
I ran two different version of my program with and without the use of the go routine, and over the same time period the one with the go routine leaked memory. 
Apologies in prematurely assuming it was the ticker. It actually calls a method to update a file...I know a very easy way to leak memory there is by leaving descriptors open, so I've made sure to have a `defered reader.Close()` as soon as I try opening it successfully. But even then... I don't give it updates yet. So it just checks file status, and then waits for the next 2 minutes.

Comment: Is `defer reader.Close()` called directly from the loop in `checkForUpdates`?  If so, that's the problem.  Deferred calls are executed on return from the function.

Comment: No, I made sure that all I did was in a completely separate method for those reasons, so that the variables I did create, would get collected once I exited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cerise Limon pointed out it is most likely your application leaking memory in the logic its doing.  In order to pinpoint exactly what is leaking memory you can use `pprof` to show the total memory in use by statement.  This is a method for answering any question like:

- "Which part of the application is using the most memory at a point in time?"
- "Which part of the application is responsible for the most memory allocations? (in byte size)"
- "which part of the application (if any) is growing in size over time"
- "how much memory is a given statement/line using at a point in time?"

Once pprof is enabled you can take memory profiles by using:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/heap > heap.0.pprof
```

You can then interact with the profile using the cli:

```
$ go tool pprof pprof/heap.3.pprof
Local symbolization failed for main: open /tmp/go-build598947513/b001/exe/main: no such file or directory
Some binary filenames not available. Symbolization may be incomplete.
Try setting PPROF_BINARY_PATH to the search path for local binaries.
File: main
Type: inuse_space
Time: Jul 30, 2018 at 6:11pm (UTC)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) svg
Generating report in profile002.svg
(pprof) top20
Showing nodes accounting for 410.75MB, 99.03% of 414.77MB total
Dropped 10 nodes (cum <= 2.07MB)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  408.97MB 98.60% 98.60%   408.97MB 98.60%  bytes.Repeat
    1.28MB  0.31% 98.91%   410.25MB 98.91%  main.(*RequestTracker).Track
    0.50MB  0.12% 99.03%   414.26MB 99.88%  net/http.(*conn).serve
         0     0% 99.03%   410.25MB 98.91%  main.main.func1
         0     0% 99.03%   410.25MB 98.91%  net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP
         0     0% 99.03%   410.25MB 98.91%  net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP
```

Which will show you how much memory is inuse in your application and which statements/lines are responsible.

What's also cool is that you can generate graphviz charts of your program in order to visualize and trace current memory usage (or memory allocations):

[image]

---

There are quite a few blog posts about pprof online (including standard documentation).

I wrote a bit about it:

- [Debugging Memory Leaks in Go](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/sre-debugging-simple-memory-leaks-in-go-e0a9e6d63d4d)
- [Go Performance Tuning Using pprof](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/sre-performance-analysis-tuning-methodology-using-a-simple-http-webserver-in-go-d475460f27ca)

And then there are many amazing resources, two of which are:

- https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/
- https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/09/24/profiling-go-with-pprof/

Comment: Thank you for all the resources, will go ahead and try pprof!